# check whether value entered in textbox exist in database without form submit in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter, validation, textbox

I have a form which has many fields,one of them is like when user inputs a particular code in input field  I need to check whether that code exists in database or not without submitting the form.Because on form submit the data would be inserted to another table.Here table from which i need to check code is different. If code exits if should display beside text box that code is correct else invalid.Can someone give provide me example for the same or solution....Thanks in advance

MY_View:

```
<input type="text" name="ref_code" id="ref_code" onblur="checkCodeStatus()" size=18 maxlength=6 required> 

<script type="text/javascript">
      function checkCodeStatus(){

      var ref_code=$("#ref_code").val();

          $.ajax({
               type:'post',
               url:'<?php echo site_url('mypage/check_code/'); ?>',
               data:{ref_code: ref_code},
               success:function(msg){
                     alert(msg);    
                                }
               });
              }

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you would to create function `check_code`.

```
function check_code(){
    $this->db->where('ref_code', $this->input->post('ref_code'));
    $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
    if($query->num_rows() >= 1){
       echo 'value does exist';
    }
}
```

Then, in your ajax call, you have to do something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:'<?php echo site_url('mypage/check_code/'); ?>',
     data:{ref_code: ref_code},
     success:function(msg){
                 if(msg.indexOf('value does exist') > -1)
                     $('#msg').html('<span style="color: green;">'+msg+"</span>");    
                 else $('#msg').html('<sapn style="color:red;">Value does not exist</span>');
             }
     });
  }
```

**EDIT**: You only have to add an HTML element near the input, like this:

```
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: You could achieve same scope using form validation with function callback. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: I don't want page to be refreshed. Instead of alert I want that msg to be displayed beside the textbox.How can i achieve this ?  @ webcrazymaniac

Comment: I have displayed it like this in success function : success: function(data) { 
                                       $('#msg').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                                    }

Comment: you got all you need. Only change `onblur="checkCodeStatus()"` to `onchange="checkCodeStatus()"` inside the input tag.

Comment: Is this another question? alert() displays the message, doesn't it? Does it work?

Comment: NO its not another question.In my question I had mentioned i want it beside the textbox. @ webcrazymaniac